# Count the total pairs of numbers that have a difference of K

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here is how I am solving this problem :

```
void solve ( int *input, int N, int K, int& count) {
    std::sort ( input, input + N);
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int find_me  = input[i] + K;
        if (std::binary_search (input + i + 1, input + N, find_me )) 
            count++;        
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

`input` has `integer` values which is guaranteed to be `unique` and `> 0` , `N` is the number of elements.

Does anybody see anything wrong with this code, I have submitted this to one programming puzzle contest and bot is saying couple of test cases are failed, I want to know what possible test case this code can fail.

Comment: "Can you spot what is wrong with my code?" is not really a suitable question for SO...

Comment: But, is `count` initialised to zero?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth : yes it is initialized to 0

Comment: Solution: insert every value into a hash-table subtracting k from the value before inserting. The iterate the list looking up every value in the hash-table, each value that exists implies it has a value that is k more than itself. This solution is O(n) time and O(n) space complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've understood the codes correctly, but it seems to me that if there does not exist a number with value `input[0] + K` in the array `input`, your loop will terminate with that `break`. I think that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Suppose my input is 1 5 3 4 2 , I am sorting it first so it becomes 1 2 3 4 5, now if my K = 2, 1 + 2 = 3 , 2 + 2 = 4, 3 + 2 = 5  found but when it comes to 4 + 2 = 6 , it will fail and stop.

Comment: @Avinash What if your input is 1 5 4 2 then? Sorting it becomes 1 2 4 5 and then if your K = 2, 1 + 2 = 3, it won't find a 3 in the array and then fail and stops. However, clearly there is a (2,4) pair in the array.

Comment: Also be sure to point out the one-past-the-end error in the for loop that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Avinash: Mark's linear algorithm would be nicer. His basic idea is to use two indices i and j, and if a[i] < a[j] + K then i++ else if a[i] > a[j] + K then j++ else count++;

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code. First, the `else break;` portion of the `if` needs to go away to avoid prematurely exiting the `for` loop. Second, you run one past the end of the loop on the last iteration. Your loop termination condition should be `i < N - 1`.

However since the items are sorted it seems likely that there's a linear complexity algorithm you could use, similar to a set intersection algorithm where you walk two indexes independently, doing the checks.